# phonegap 2.8 Capture video Duration always return 0 in android 4.2.2

Tags: android, cordova

iam using phonegap 2.8.1 when i try to get duration of captured video in  android 4.2.2 (nexus 4) always return 0 ? why i tested on several devices all are working except in android 4.2.2 , then i change phonegap version to 2.7 then also same problem

```
 navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function(mediaFiles){

      var i, len;

      for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        //uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
                    var mediaFile = mediaFiles[i];
                                          console.log(mediaFile.fullPath);


                                        mediaFile.getFormatData(
                                                                function(f){
                                                                var length= Math.ceil(f.duration);

                                                                  if(length > 60){


                                                                  navigator.notification.alert("Video Capture Limit exceeded Max limit 60 sec");
                                                                  } else {

                                                                                        $('.upBtn').show('1000');
                                                                  $('#startNow').text('Capture Again');
                                                                  var videoNode = document.querySelector('video');
                                                                  videoNode.src = fullTempPath;
                                                                $('#time').html("Dutration of Video == " + vidLength +" sec" );

                                                                  } 
                                                                },
                                                                function(){
                                                                navigator.notification.alert("Try Again..");

                                                                }
                                                                );




      }


      }, function(e){

       navigator.notification.alert("Try Again.. Camera Error" + e);




      }, {duration: 10000});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying this myself! But why not use the

```
{duration: 60}
```

when you call

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function(mediaFiles)
```

change it to be

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function(mediaFiles), {duration: 60}
```

This is from the api in the 2.7 version of phonegap. The duration sets a limit on the duration of recording. The code will have to be changed to suit this way. It is supposed to be supported I cant get it to work on my dev. phone but it works according to phonegap groups. Hope this helps